# "Share this link" HTML Widget

Tags: html, widget, social-networking

Are you aware of any HTML Widget (Jquery?) that can be integrated in a dynamic web page allowing users to share the visited link to well known social networks like "Delicious, Facebook, Twitter..etc etc."?

It would be cool a **customizable** solution that can be tuned to match the **graphic layout (colors, font)** of the site.

I would like to integrate this feature on [StackPrinter](http://stackprinter.appspot.com) web application, allowing users to share [good questions](http://stackprinter.appspot.com/export?format=HTML&service=stackoverflow&printer=false&question=194812) to social networks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AddThis](http://www.addthis.com/) and [ShareThis](http://sharethis.com/) (I think AddThis allows a wider selection of sharing methods) are the two that I see used the most.

Answer (score 1):

I use [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com/)